# Share Image to Telegram on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, telegram

I am trying to share a picture from my app to Telegram. I want to do this without `UIActivityViewController` if possible. I have bellow the code that almost does exactly what I want. It opens telegram, it lets me choose who to send to, but it doesn't share the picture, only a url path.

This is the code that I've wrote:

In the following code, `url` is address to the image on the phone that I'm trying to share.

```
let telegramUrlString = "tg://msg_url?url=\(url)"
if let urlString = telegramUrlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
    if let telegramUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(telegramUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(telegramUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            completion(ErrorCode.CANNOT_SHARE_ON_TELEGRAM, nil)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that there is not a url scheme that allows you to send an image straight to the chat. You are able to send links, but not images.

Comment: @wazowski Thank you for the info. Actually, that was what I was thinking too, but I needed to get confirmation from someone else.

Comment: yes, I was working in a solution for WA, but I could not do it like this. Same problem XD